# How to convert a type Any List to a type Double (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mean, databricks

I am new to Scala and I would like to understand some basic stuff.

First of all, I need to **calculate the average** of a **certain column** of a **DataFrame** and use the result as a double type variable.

After some Internet research I was able to calculate the average and at the same time pass it into a **List type Any** by using the following command:

```
val avgX_List = mainDataFrame.groupBy().agg(mean("_c1")).collect().map(_(0)).toList
```

where "**_c1**" is the **second column** of my **dataframe**. This line of code returns a List with type **List[Any]**.

To pass the result into a variable I used the following command:

```
var avgX = avgX_List(0)
```

hoping that the var avgX would be type double automatically but that didn't happen obviously.

So now let the questions begin:

1. What does `map(_(0)) do`? I know the basic definition of the `map()` transformation but I can't find an explanation with this exact argument
2. I know that by using `.toList` method in the end of the command my result will be a List with type `Any`. Is there a way that I could change this into List which contains type `Double` elements? Or even convert this one
3. Do you think that it would be much more appropriate to pass the column of my Dataframe into a List[Double] and then calculate the average of its elements?
4. Is the solution I showed above at any point of view correct based on my problem? I know that "it is working" is different from "correct solution"?

Summing up, I need to calculate the average of a certain column of a Dataframe and have the result as a double type variable.

Note that: I am Greek and I find it hard sometimes to understand some English coding "slang".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map(_(0))` is a shortcut for `map( (r: Row) => r(0) )`, which is in turn a shortcut for `map( (r: Row) => r.apply(0) )`. The `apply` method returns `Any`, and so you are losing the right type. Try using `map(_.getAs[Double](0))` or `map(_.getDouble(0))` instead.

Collecting all entries of the column and then computing the average would be highly counterproductive, because you'd have to send huge amounts of data to the master node, and then do all the calculations on this single central node. That would be the exact opposite of what Spark is good for.

You also don't need `collect(...).toList`, because you can access the 0-th entry directly (it doesn't matter whether you get it from an `Array` or from a `List`). Since you are collapsing everything into a single `Row` anyway, you could get rid of the `map` step entirely by reordering the methods a little bit:

```
val avgX = mainDataFrame.groupBy().agg(mean("_c1")).collect()(0).getDouble(0)
```

It can be written even shorter using the `first` method:

```
val avgX = mainDataFrame.groupBy().agg(mean("_c1")).first().getDouble(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. So you think that the solution I have found is efficient based on the result I want to achieve? 
Also, when you say the `collectAsList` already exists, you mean that it exists in the `.toList` part of the command? 
Finally using `map(_.getAs[Double](0))` gives me this error: `error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => x$2.getAs[Double](0))` . Do you have any idea what this means?

Comment: @ArisKantas Ah, no, sorry, forget the `collectAsList` part, it's a java-compatibility thing, it actually returns a java.util.List, probably not what you want. Does the `map(_.getDouble(0))` work, or what happened to the error you've just reported?

Comment: The final suggestion of your answer worked! I have to study much more in order to understand how these methods work exactly. Especially map(). Could you briefly expain to me why map() is not needed in this occassion? Thanks on behalf!

Answer (score 1):

```
#Any dataType in Scala can't be directly converted to Double.
#Use toString & then toDouble on final captured result.

#Eg-

#scala> x
#res22: Any = 1.0

#scala> x.toString.toDouble
#res23: Double = 1.0

#Note- Instead of using map().toList() directly use (0)(0) to get the final value from your resultset.


#TestSample(Scala)-

val wa = Array("one","two","two")
val wrdd = sc.parallelize(wa,3).map(x=>(x,1))
val wdf = wrdd.toDF("col1","col2")
val x = wdf.groupBy().agg(mean("col2")).collect()(0)(0).toString.toDouble

#O/p-
#scala> val x = wdf.groupBy().agg(mean("col2")).collect()(0)(0).toString.toDouble
#x: Double = 1.0
```

Comment: Where did you see a `collect()(0)(0)` in my code? It's the same as `collect()(0).apply(0)`, so it loses all type information and returns `Any`. Not that I claimed anything different...

Comment: It’s my sample code. I’m just saying that getDouble() is not available on variable of Any data type.

Comment: It is available on `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`. Again, I never claimed that `getDouble()` should be invoked on `Any`. Your answer attempts to solve a problem that isn't there.

Comment: I checked it ! it's working fine :-) ```val wa = Array("one","two","two")
val wrdd = sc.parallelize(wa,3).map(x=>(x,1))
val wdf = wrdd.toDF("col1","col2")
wdf.groupBy().agg(mean("col2")).collect()(0).getDouble(0)```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. Could you explain to me what does `collect()(0)(0)` does? 

Also if I want to convert a Dataframe into a List, what is your suggestion so that I can take a correct type List (i.e. Double) ? my aproach is this : `var trainingCoordList = trainingCoordDataFrame.collect().toList` but it returns a type `List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` which I don't know what it is exactly!

Comment: In your approach you're getting a list but you only need first mean/aggregated value(since in groupBy you didn't mentioned any column name).
 So 'collect()(0)(0)' will return first value of the list returned by 'collect()(0)' & it's data type will be Any.
Then on this value (of dataType Any) you can use toSting & toDouble to get the mean value casted to double.

Comment: @MIKHILNAGARALE Now I got it! I appreciate your answer. So  `collect()(0)(0)` returns the first element from the List and `collect()(0)` returns the whole list?

Comment: @MIKHILNAGARALE Yeah, I kind-of assumed that it should be working fine, but now you've tricked me into downloading the latest version of spark with hadoop on a laptop where I don't really need it :)

Comment: You can check it on spark local :-) like I use to quickly regenerate the user scenario :-)